# AzureDevOps Onpremise Test Plan

Tags: azure-devops

I am not able to create a new test plan, a test suit in onpremise devops instance. Although the installed setup is an enterprise edition.

Now how do i configure the test plans ?

Comment: I was able to create the test plans some days back. But now i am unable to do.

Comment: Any error message when you tried creating new test plans? Can you see the test plans section on your project ui portal?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [*Basic + Test Plans* license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels) to be able to *add* and *manage* test plans/suites/test-cases. Someone with a *Basic* license can work with the Test Plan and other details, but they cannot add.

In addition to the license, the *Project* provides a few different access controls to limit which users are allowed to modify Test Plans and Executions.

1. **Settings -> Boards:Project Configuration -> Areas**. It might not be obvious, but both *Test Plans* and *Test Cases* are associated with an *Area* and *Iteration* in the backlog. To apply fine-grained control over test-plans, you apply the permissions to the *Area*.

   [image]
2. **Settings -> General:Permissions**. These are the Permission groups within your Project. There is a setting that generally controls general permissions for creating, running and viewing test executions:

   [image: Permissions]